# Simple Race Condition in Go HTTP Handler - Is this really a race condition?

Tags: go, race-condition

Given the code below, I'm trying to understand WHY the Go race detector (`go run -race example.go`) does not complain about a race condition.

```
var count int

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/a/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        count++ 
        fmt.Println(count)
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/b/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        count++
        fmt.Println(count)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

It's my understanding that the Go HTTP Server responds to all requests in a separate goroutine. With that in mind, would not the increments made to the global count variable by the handler functions happen in a goroutine that is separate from the main goroutine and thus, constitute a data race?

If this is not a data race, I'd very much like to know why.

Comment: How would you fix this data race ? You can't pass a channel to func. Would a WaitGroup work here ?

Comment: @Sridhar You can use a mutex or sync/atomic to atomically increment the value.

Comment: @Joshua useful warning at the top of the sync/atomic package docs.

Comment: @Sridhar yes, dragons beware...

Comment: Lots of races: `636977
636977
636978
636979
636980
636981
636981
636982
636983
636984
636984
636985
636985
636986
` — hitting each of `/a` and `/b` with `wrk -c 200 -t 4` and `GOMAXPROCS=4`. Just need to ramp up the concurrency!

Comment: Oh, ++ for actually running the stress test, @elithrar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a data race, the race detector however does not report races that don't happen. You need to make sure that there are concurrent calls in your test, and ensuring `GOMAXPROCS>1` can help flush them out as well.

Comment: GOMAXPROCS>1 is very apt! For new Gophers like myself, to understand why, read: http://www.goinggo.net/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html

Answer (score 5):

That's a race condition. [False negatives can happen with the race checker.](https://talks.golang.org/2015/dynamic-tools.slide#12)

The race checker is dynamic: rather than checking the source for problems, it only can only see if read and a write *actually occur* with no sync operation in between. There's no synchronizing operation in your code, but if one occurs in `net/http` between the increments, it'll be fooled.  [Its author suggests](https://talks.golang.org/2015/dynamic-tools.slide#12), essentially, running concurrent stress tests to shake out problems:

> - write good **concurrent** tests
> - have continuous build with race detector
> - run integration tests
> - run race-enabled canaries in production

In Go 1.4 and below, you should also make sure your program runs on more than one core with, e.g., [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/). In Go 1.5, to be released around the end of 2015, GOMAXPROCS will run your code on all available cores by default.

Answer (score 3):

`count++` is a data race. It does not happen atomically. It is the same as:

```
count = count + 1
```

If the race detector doesn't see it, you probably are not hitting the server hard enough.